# What is the correct syntax for updating a bit column

Tags: sql-server

When updating/inserting into a bit column (on Microsoft SQL Server), what is the correct syntax?

```
CREATE TABLE USER_ACCOUNT
(
     USER_NAME VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
     IS_ENABLED BIT   
)
```

It must be one of these, but which one is the recommended best practice?

```
Insert into user_account values ('ABC', 0);
Insert into user_account values ('ABC', '0');
Insert into user_account values ('ABC', False);
Insert into user_account values ('ABC', 'False');
```

Comment: Is this a quiz or an actual question? If question, just try, if quiz please remove

Comment: when you are using BIT then 0 or 1 can be inserted we can use False or true @akshay

Comment: but it works when i use '0' as well. Is this wrong ? @mohan111

Comment: it will take only 0 or 1

Comment: it takes 0,1, 'false', 'true', I tried.

Comment: This is because all of those can be converted to a BIT: ["The string values TRUE and FALSE can be converted to bit values: TRUE is converted to 1 and FALSE is converted to 0"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ie/library/ms177603.aspx). So it works with TRUE and FALSE *as strings*, i.e. `'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'`, but not as non-strings, as `TRUE` and `FALSE` aren't keywords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Except

```
Insert into user_account values ('ABC', False);
```

all other queries will work. `False` not enclosed in single quotes cannot be converted to a `BIT` value

Answer (score 2):

Both can work:

```
Insert into user_account values ('ABC', 'False');
Insert into user_account values ('ABC', 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

To update column

update transactions_stoppage set is_deleted = 0 where is_deleted is null